# How do I evaluate $\int_{-i}^{i}{\dfrac{x^i}{1-x^{2i+2}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the value of: $$\int_{-i}^{i}{\dfrac{x^i}{1-x^{2i+2}}} dx$$

Where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

I attempted: $x^{i+1}=k; (i+1)x^{i} dx= dk$ This transforms the integral $$\int_{-i}^{i}{\dfrac{x^i}{1-x^{2i+2}}} dx$$ into:$$2\int_{0}^{i e^{\pi/2}}{\dfrac{1}{(i+1)(1-k^{2})}} dk$$ (Even function)

This results in a a very weird value.
Also, substituting $x=ik$ results in a different value.

I feel like I am missing a better method of solving this. What is the correct value of this integral and what is the correct method to evaluate it?

Also find the value of $$\int_{-i}^{i}{\dfrac{x^i}{1+x^{2i+2}}} dx$$

Comment: What does $x^i$ mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

When $x$ takes the values on the segment from $-i$ to $i$ it takes the value $-e^{-\pi/2}i$, and at this point the denominator becomes $0$, so the function is not integrable on that trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least compute the value for half the interval
$$\int \frac{x^n}{1-x^{2 n+2}}\,dx=\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(x^{n+1}\right)}{n+1}$$
$$\int_0^n \frac{x^n}{1-x^{2 n+2}}\,dx=\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(n^{n+1}\right)}{n+1}$$
$$\int_0^i \frac{x^i}{1-x^{2 i+2}}\,dx=\frac{1-i}{2}\, \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(i^{1+i}\right)=\frac{1+i}{2}\,\tan ^{-1}\left(e^{-\pi /2}\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

I think I have something.

$I=\int_{-i}^i \frac{x^i dx}{1-x^{2(i+1)}}=\int_{-i}^i \frac{x^i dx}{(1-x^{i+1})(1+x^{i+1})}$

$u=x^{i+1}. du=(i+1)x^i dx$

$i^{i+1} = i (i^i)=ie^{-\pi /2}$

$-i^{i+1}=(-i)i^i=-ie^{-\pi/2}$

$\int_{-ie^{-\pi/2}}^{ie^{-\pi/2}} \frac{du}{(i+1)(1-u^2)}$

$u=\sin \theta. du=\cos \theta d\theta$

$\int \frac{du}{(1-u^2)}=\int \sec\theta d\theta=\ln |\sec\theta + \tan \theta|+C=\ln |\frac{1+u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}| +C$

$I = (\frac{1}{1+i})[\ln |\frac{1+ ie^{-\pi/2}}{\sqrt{1+e^{-\pi}}}|-\ln |\frac{1-ie^{-\pi/2}}{\sqrt{1+e^{-\pi}}}|]=(\frac{1}{i+1})\ln |\frac{1+ie^{-\pi/2}}{1-ie^{-\pi/2}}|$

$e^v=\frac{1+ie^{-\pi/2}}{1-ie^{-\pi/2}}=\frac{1-e^{-\pi}+2ie^{-\pi/2}}{1+e^{-\pi}}$

$e^v=re^{i\theta}. r^2= \frac{(1-e^{-\pi})^2+4e^{-\pi}}{(1+e^{-\pi})^2}=1 . \tan \theta=\frac{2e^{-\pi/2}}{1-e^{-\pi}}$

$v=i\theta = i\arctan (\frac{2e^{-\pi/2}}{1-e^{-\pi}})$

$I=v/(i+1)$

$I= \frac{i(1-i)\arctan (\frac{2e^{-\pi/2}}{1-e^{-\pi}})}{2}$

Comment: The integrand has a pole at $t=\pi/2$ if the path on the complex plane is assumed to be a straight line through the end points. Is this finite value meaningful at all? Does it represent a principal value deformation?